# How to use wxWidgets on eclipse under Ubuntu

Tags: eclipse, ubuntu, wxwidgets

I am using ubuntu 15.04 under VMware Player.
I have eclipse 3.8.1 and wxWidgets 3.0.

I have installed wxWidgets by:

```
sudo apt-get install libwxbase3.0-0-unofficial  libwxbase3.0-dev  libwxgtk3.0-0-unofficial libwxgtk3.0-dev wx3.0-headers wx-common libwxbase3.0-dbg libwxgtk3.0-dbg wx3.0-i18n wx3.0-examples wx3.0-doc
```

I open a new c++ project with the following setting:

- Project -> Properties -> C/C++ Build -> Settings -> Cross G++ Compiler -> Miscellaneous -> Other flags -> append "`wx-config --cxxflags`"
- Project -> Properties -> C/C++ Build -> Settings -> Cross G++ Linker -> Miscellaneous -> Linker flags -> append "`wx-config --libs`"
- Project -> Properties -> C/C++ Build -> Settings -> Cross G++ Compiler -> Includes -> add "/usr/include/wx-3.0-unofficial/"

I then copy the example from [here](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/stable/overview_helloworld.html). The problem is that those declaration of the variables defined by wxWidgets did not found. Anyone knows how to solve it?

Comment: Are you sure Eclipse supports backticks notation? You might need to execute `wx-config --cxxflags` in the terminal and copy and paste the results in Eclipse. You also, really, really need to show (at least the beginning of) the error messages you're getting.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to capture the error msg. Basically, I follow https://wiki.wxwidgets.org/Eclipse to do the setting. I can compile the code without eclipse, by `g++ main.cpp \`pkg-config wx-config --libs\` -o test`.